# Using QMap and getting compile error messages

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I am trying to use a "QMap", in the class prototype:

```
    QMap<QString, TargetsInfo*> m_targets;
```

In an access method I have:

```
    TargetsInfo* TargetsModel::addTarget(int division, int camera, int map) const {
        TargetsInfo* target = getTarget(division, camera, map);

        if (target == nullptr) {
            const QString key = makeKey(division, camera, map);
            target = new TargetsInfo();

            if ( target != nullptr ) {
                m_targets.insert(key, target);
            }
        }
        return target;
    }

    TargetsInfo* TargetsModel::getTarget(int division, int camera, int map) const {
        const QString key = makeKey(division, camera, map);
        QMap<QString, TargetsInfo*>::iterator itr = m_targets.find(key);
        return (its == m_targets.end()) ? nullptr : itr.value();
    }
```

When I compile I get the following errors which I am struggling to see what is wrong:

```
    C2663: 'QMap<QString, TargetInfo *>::insert': 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
    C2440: 'initialising': cannot convert from 'QMap<QString, TargetInfo *>::const_iterator' to 'QMap::<QString, TargetInfo *>::iterator'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Comment: Why is `addTarget` marked `const`? I would expect that adding something somewhere modifies the container.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, thank you, cut and paste error, I removed the const and that got rid of the C2663 error, still have the C2440 message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second error change

```
QMap<QString, TargetsInfo*>::iterator itr = ...
```

to

```
QMap<QString, TargetsInfo*>::const_iterator itr = ...
```

Your `getTarget` method is const so `m_targets.find` returns a const iterator (otherwise you could change `m_targets` inside your supposedly const method).

For the first error, remove `const` from your `addTarget` method. Obviously a method which adds items to `m_targets` should not be const.

Comment: A typical case where `auto` really shines as it will deduce the correct iterator type automatically.